# How to get page views on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to get page views on JavaScript?

I want to get and display how many times a page is viewed, just like Stack Overflow.

How to do it by JavaScript? Thx!

Comment: If you tried anything for yourself, post your code in your question. If you haven't tried anything for yourself, hire a programmer to do it.

Comment: That's not possible with client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use JavaScript to track how many page views in past 24 hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474029/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-track-how-many-page-views-in-past-24-hours)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in javascript. You've to use browsers local storage to store the page view count to use it. You can use either [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

`sessionStorage` will work like php session and will only be available through one browsing session, if you close the browser then sessionStorage data will be removed by browser. But, `localStorage` will not be removed by browser until user manually delete browser data.

I'm gonna show you two implementations:

**Using localStorage:** you can store a variable into localStorage which can be used to count the page view. :

```
var myStorage = window.localStorage, pageCount;
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
   if(!myStorage.getItem("pageCount")){
      myStorage.setItem('pageCount', 1);
   } else {
      pageCount = myStorage.getItem("pageCount");
      pageCount = pageCount + 1;
      myStorage.setItem('pageCount', pageCount );
   }
   console.log('page view count', myStorage.getItem("pageCount"));
});
```

Or **using window.sessionStorage** :

```
var mySession = window.sessionStorage, pageCount;
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
   if(!mySession.getItem("pageCount")){
      mySession.setItem('pageCount', 1);
   } else {
      pageCount = mySession.getItem("pageCount");
      pageCount = pageCount + 1;
      mySession.setItem('pageCount', pageCount );
   }
   console.log('page view count of current browsing session', mySession.getItem("pageCount"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using client-side JavaScript will not get the job done.

However, if you still want to use JavaScript then you should take a look at Node.js. Ideally, you would want to record the number of unique sessions, although, you can still record a page refresh as a page view.

This can be done with the following piece of code provided that you know how Node.js works:

```
var http = require('http'); // Require HTTP module
var pageViewCount = 0; // Declare and initialise the page view count

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }); // Headers

  pageViewCount++; // Increase the page view count for every successful page load request

  console.log('There are currently ' + pageViewCount + ' views'); // Output in console the amount of total page views
  res.end();
});

server.listen(8000);
console.log('Server is currently running');
```

You can find more information regarding Node.js here: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/

Keep in mind that this answer requires some knowledge of Node.js but confirms that server-side JavaScript can be used to provide a solution to this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

With nodejs (serverside javascript) and express ( a library) you could do the following:

```
 var counter = 0;
 var app = require("express");
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  counter++;
  res.render("main.ejs",{counter});
});

 app.listen(80);
```

*main.ejs* should look like this:

```
 The page was visited <%= counter %> times...
```

Comment: 1. It is not a page view counter. It should depend on page URL
2. This counter is stored in memory and will be cleared after service restart

Comment: 1) what is it then? 2) yes, however this is just a starting point. I dont do the ops job...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to store that in Database.